# How to visualize compact space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am reading Walter rudin's book on analysis, I am thoroughly enjoying it
although, in the second chapter basic topology i am trying to get a feel for compact spaces, anything that can make that sub chapter more intuitive.
I have been able to come up with imaginative methods for other definitions and theorems, with the help of which i can those concepts , to some extant, understand intuitively. 
but compact spaces are a bit tricky to visualize, any help will be useful

Thanks

Comment: The Heine-Borel theorem states that a set in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. I personally find this latter characterization to be easier to visualize.

Comment: Compact sets are in some sense "small" (hence the name). This is also reflected in the general definition, namely that you should, for any open cover, be able to find a *finite* subcover.

Comment: In analysis you can get away with thinking of compactness as sequential compactness, at least up to a point: that is, compact spaces are spaces where sequences have convergent subsequences. This produces a totally opposite intuition to "smallness": it says that compact spaces are spaces that have all the points they "should" have, and in particular correctly suggests that it is possible to make spaces compact by *adding* points to them ("compactification").